# Multithreading and Critical Sections Use - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, winapi, critical-section

I'm a little confused as to the proper use of critical sections in multithreaded applications.  In my application there are several objects (some circular buffers and a serial port object) that are shared among threads.  Should access of these objects always be placed within critical sections, or only at certain times?  I suspect only at certain times because when I attempted to wrap each use with an `EnterCriticalSection` / `LeaveCriticalSection` I ran into what seemed to be a deadlock condition.  Any insight you may have would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you share a resource across threads, and some of those threads read while others write, then it must be protected always.

It's hard to give any more advice without knowing more about your code, but here are some general points to keep in mind.

1) Critical sections protect *resources*, not *processes*.

2) Enter/leave critical sections in the same order across all threads.  If thread A enters Foo, then enters Bar, then thread B must enter Foo and Bar in the same order.  If you don't, you could create a race.

3) Entering and leaving must be done in opposite order.  Example, since you entered Foo then entered Bar, you must leave Bar before leaving Foo.  If you don't do this, you could create a deadlock.

4) Keep locks for the shortest time period reasonably possible.  If you're done with Foo before you start using Bar, release Foo before grabbing Bar.  But you still have to keep the ordering rules in mind from above.  In every thread that uses both Foo and Bar, you must acquire and release in the same order:

```
  Enter Foo
  Use Foo
  Leave Foo
  Enter Bar
  Use Bar
  Leave Bar
```

5) If you only read 99.9% of the time and write 0.1% of the time, don't try to be clever.  You still have to enter the crit sec even when you're only reading.  This is because you don't want a write to start when your'e in the middle of a read.

6) Keep the critical sections granular.  Each critical section should protect one resource, not multiple resources.  If you make the critical sections too "big", you could serialize your application or create a very mysterious set of deadlocks or races.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I'll be sure to keep those tips in mind, especially no. 6.  I think I'm still missing something, though.  Does entering a critical section prevent other threads from accessing all cross-thread resources, or does `EnterCriticalSection` / `LeaveCriticalSection` perform some magic that prevents other threads from accessing only the referenced resources they encapsulate?  Or, is there a way to associate a resource with a `CRITICAL_SECTION` object that I have missed completely?

Comment: It's not strictly true that you always have to acquire a lock when reading if there are writers -- there are data structures and access patterns for which this is not the case.  But it's a good rule of thumb.  Also, if readers being blocked is a frequent bottleneck, it's important to know there are also such things as reader-writer locks which allow concurrent reads.

Comment: @asveikau:  Yes, this was only intended to be rules of thumb appropriate for a new multithreadded programmer.  Also re: reader-writer locks (aka Gates), unless the reads are long-lived, it is often slower to use a Gate than to just use a crit sec. See this article for more: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1454462

Comment: @Jim:  Entering Crit Sec Foo does not effect another thread trying to enter Crit Sec Bar.  Does that answer your question, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @John Dibling: Sort of.  Let's say that I have a critical section Foo, and in it is accessed a circular buffer object.  How do the other threads know to wait to access the circular buffer object, until the critical section has completed?  Or, is it that `EnterCriticalSection` stalls the second thread until `LeaveCriticalSection` is called in the first thread?  If that is the case, should calls to `EnterCriticalSection` and `LeaveCriticalSection` reference the **same** `CRITICAL_SECTION` object?

Comment: @Jim:  You must reference the same CRITICAL_SECTION across threads.  It is typically set up in the main thread, and a pointer to it is sent along to each worker thread via the worker thread's main function.  In Windows, `ThreadProc` takes a `void*` to accommodate this kind of thing.

Comment: @John Dibling: Thank you.  I believe that answers my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use a C++ wrapper around the critical section which supports RAII:

```
{
    CriticalSectionLock lock ( mutex_ );

    Do stuff...
}
```

The constructor for the lock acquires the mutex and the destructor releases the mutex even if an exception is thrown.

Try not to gain more more than one lock at a time, and try to avoid calling functions outside of your class while holding locks; this helps avoid gaining locks in different places, so you tend to get fewer possibilities for deadlocks.

If you must gain more than one lock at the same time, sort the locks by their address and gain them in order. That way multiple processes gain the same locks in the same order without co-ordination.

With an IO port, consider whether you need to lock output at the same time as input - often you have a case where something tries to write, then expects to read, or visa-versa. If you have two locks, then you can get a deadlock if one thread writes then reads, and the other reads then writes.  Often having one thread which does the IO and a queue of requests solves that, but that's a bit more complicated than just wrapping calls up with locks, and without much more detail I can't recommend it.

Comment: +1 for avoiding calling functions outside of your class. I would take this to the next level and say that in general you should avoid calling library code whenever possible while holding a lock. (Unless you have a very good reason.)